# Plotting a line between two points in a datapoint in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have a data that looks something like this.

```
User | Start | End
A    |  1    | 3
B    |  2    | 5
C    |  1    | 3
D    |  4    | 5
E    |  3    | 4
F    |  1    | 5
```

Now using ggplot2, I want to make a graph that looks something like the following.
[image]

I have tried using `geom_line()` and `geom_tile()` but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: See `geom_segment`.

Comment: As mentioned by jdobres, you may need `df1 %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% ggplot() + geom_segment(aes(x = rn, y = User, xend = End, yend = User, col = User))`

Comment: What you are describing is a "dumbbell chart". if you search for that you'll see many examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do this -

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -User) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= value, y= User, group = User, color = name)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(size=4) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(User = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), Start = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L), End = c(3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 3):

The [ggalt](/questions/tagged/ggalt) package has a `geom_dumbbell()` function.
The data can be used *as is*, no pivoting is required.

```
library(ggalt)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Start, xend = End, y = User)) + 
  geom_dumbbell()
```

[image]

The plot can be customised to simulate OPs expected result:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Start, xend = End, y = User)) + 
  geom_dumbbell(size = 1, shape = 1, size_x = 2.5, size_xend = 2.5, stroke = 1.5) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev, labels = NULL) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Please, note that the direction of the y axis has changed: `User` `A` to `F` runs from top to bottom as requested.

`geom_dumbbell()` can be further customised to  simulate the color scheme of [Ronak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68417584/3817004):

```
pal <- scales::hue_pal()(2)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Start, xend = End, y = User)) + 
  geom_dumbbell(size = 1, colour = pal[2], size_x = 2.5, 
                size_xend = 2.5, colour_xend = pal[1], stroke = 1.5) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev, name = NULL) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

#### Data

```
df1 <- data.table::fread(
"User | Start | End
A    |  1    | 3
B    |  2    | 5
C    |  1    | 3
D    |  4    | 5
E    |  3    | 4
F    |  1    | 5")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    ggplot() + 
      geom_segment(aes(x = rn, y = User, xend = End, yend = User, col = User))
``
```